# Timeline cursor missing

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

My timeline cursor in the video sequence editor is either missing or hidden. I reinstalled blender to no avail. How can I get it back?

[image: Timeline cursor missing]
Edit: I found my timeline cursor as here, but it won't move at all.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I found my timeline cursor as here, but it won't move at all.

In Blender you cannot do that with **Left** click, you have to **Right** click and drag the cursor around your timeline.
Hope this helps.
All the best..